# hadoop, python, subprocess failed with code 127

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to run very simple task with mapreduce.

mapper.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

my txt file:

```
qwerty
asdfgh
zxc
```

Command line to run the job:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.8.0.jar \
-input /user/cloudera/In/test.txt \
-output /user/cloudera/test \
-mapper /home/cloudera/Documents/map.py \
-file /home/cloudera/Documents/map.py
```

Error:

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1490617885665_0008_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

How to fix this and run the code?
When I use `cat /home/cloudera/Documents/test.txt | python /home/cloudera/Documents/map.py` it works fine

**!!!!!UPDATE**

Something wrong with my *.py file. I have copied file from github 'tom white hadoop book' and everything is working fine.

But I cant understand what is the reason. It is not the permissions and charset (if I am not wrong). What else can it be?

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same problem.

**Issue:**
When the python file is created in Windows environment the new line character is **CRLF**.
My hadoop runs on Linux which understands the newline character as **LF**

[image]

**Solution:**
After changing the **CRLF** to **LF** the step ran successfully.

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue, many thanks!
I used Notepad++, Edit>EOL conversion > unix

Answer (score 1):

In `-mapper` argument you should set command, for running on cluster nodes. So there are no /home/cloudera/Documents/map.py file there. 
Files that you pass with `-files` option are placed in working directory, so you can simply use it in this way: `./map.py`

I don't remember what permissions are set to this file, so if there are no execute permissions use it as `python map.py`

so the full command is

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.8.0.jar \
-input /user/cloudera/In/test.txt \
-output /user/cloudera/test \
-mapper "python map.py" \
-file /home/cloudera/Documents/map.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your mapper.py or reducer.py.for example:

1. Not using `#!/usr/bin/env python` on top of files.
2. Syntax or logical error in your python codes. (for example print has different syntax in python2 and python3.)

Answer (score 0):

First Check `python --version`. If output of `python --version` is

```
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3       
sudo apt install python        
sudo apt install python-minimal

You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.
```

Install python by using  `sudo apt install python` and run your hadoop job

On my PC it worked and finally it's working

Comment: On WLS I also needed to install python first to make it running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

On local HADOOP 3.2.1 on macOS, I have solved my issue `java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127` here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61624913/4201275

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume this is your streaming job that is how it looks in windows. The `.py` file has new line character is **CRLF.** So you need do manually the clean up **CRLF** to **LF** or use this SED command and you should be good.

```
!sed -i -e 's/\r$//' WordCount/reducer.py 
!sed -i -e 's/\r$//' WordCount/mapper.py
```

I used the `!` here to tell the Python notebook that I am executing in a VM machine on Windows

```
!hadoop jar {JAR_FILE} \
  -files WordCount/reducer.py,WordCount/mapper.py \
  -mapper mapper.py \
  -reducer reducer.py \
  -input {HDFS_DIR}/alice.txt \
  -output {HDFS_DIR}/wordcount-output \
  -cmdenv PATH={PATH}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue my installing python3 on all the docker containers.
Docker containers:

- namenode
- datanode(s)
- resourcemanager
- nodemanager

```bash
apt update
apt install python3
```

If that does not solve the issue, then this might:

- Make your `mapper.py` and `reducer.py` as executable

  ```bash
     chmod 777 mapper.py reducer.py
  ```
- And add the shebang at the top of both scripts

  ```bash
     #!/usr/bin/env python3
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As it may be the case for someone else beside myself...: it might be due to the shebang at the top of the file(s).

For instance, if you have `#!/usr/bin/env python` and `python` is not recognized in your system (`$ which python` returns *blank* or `python not found`), it will throw that very unspecific error. To solve it, you can just change it to what you might actually have: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (or install).